# How to externalize parts of a docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to externalize some parts of a `docker-compose.yml` so I could reuse those fragments in multiple projects. My goal is to build some kind of `docker-compose.base.yml`:

This is my file as of now without externalization:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  hello-docker:
    image: $REGISTRY/hello-docker:latest
    env_file: '.env'
    environment:
      - some.profile=values
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    stop_grace_period: 60s
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        order: start-first
        failure_action: rollback
    healthcheck:
      test: ...
```

Now I want to move definitions like `version` definition, `env_file`, `volumes`, `stop_grace_period`, `deploy`, `healthcheck` to a base file, so that my project specific file inherits them and only consists of:

```
services:
  hello-docker:
    image: ...
    environment: ...
    ports: ...
```

Is that possible at all?
Sidenote:

- I'm not looking for the `extends` keyword, as this has been deprecated!
- I'm not looking for a solution to externalize some commands *within* the docker-compose.yml. It must be placed in it's own file.

I know the use of `yaml anchors`, but that would work only inside the same docker-compose file. Yaml anchors lose their functionality if placed into a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply multiple `docker-compose.yml` files using the `-f` flag. For example:

```sh
$ cat docker-compose.base.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  hello-docker:
    image: busybox
    command: env
    environment:
      - BASE=foo
      - VERSION=BASE

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  hello-docker:
    environment:
      - EXTEND=bar
      - VERSION=EXTEND

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose.yml up
...
hello-docker_1  | BASE=foo
hello-docker_1  | VERSION=EXTEND
hello-docker_1  | EXTEND=bar
```

Comment: you can run `docker compose config`, to render the full compose config for inspection.

Comment: @TheFool Ah, nice one :)

Comment: But my `docker-compose.base` configuration should of course not be bound to a concrete service! I want to add some kind of "global configuration" that I could inherit in all of my services, regardless how the services are named. Of course not all of my services are named `hello-docker`...

Comment: I created a basic `app` service in `docker-compose.base.yml`. This way, all of my applications are named `_app`, but which is not a problem. Because deployment to swarm will add the stack name before, and deployment in docker only can add `container_name`.

Comment: If you just want to include a part of YAML, try anchors with this base-extend solution.

Comment: The ".env" file used implicitely by docker-compose if they exists at the same location. does that solve this "global configuration" requirement?